# Bootstrap-select not working with HTMX partials

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect, htmx

I am trying to use [Bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) with [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) partials in Django. When a specific element is changed, htmx will return a partial html containing only the dropdown, such as:

```
<select id="myDropdown" class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

When loading the main page initially which contains the CDNs alongside myDropdown, selectpicker works fine. However, later when myDropdown gets returned by HTMX, selectpicker doesn't work, getting a display: None !important. This behaviour is exactly as if when rendering the partial html, the CDNs are not available for usage.

If instead of using class="selectpicker I use $(function(){ $('#myDropdown').selectpicker();}); it does work. The problem now is that there is a second where myDropdown isn't styled at all, before the JS function kicks in.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or bypass it in a clever way?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue, resolved it by reloading bootstrap-select's selectpicker in my base.html:

```
htmx.on('htmx:afterSwap', function (event) {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('reload');
})
```